# What is the difference between span type client and span type server?

Tags: opentracing, jaeger

What is the difference between `span.kind=server` and `span.kind=client`in terms of OpenTracing? How do I know which one to pick? What does exactly it mean?

E.g. there is my service Foo which is initially called by an external service Bar. I start tracing on my Foo side and the logic is to call another service Buzz in my system to continue the flow chain. I would rather assume that external service Bar is a `client`, but I can't start my trace from there. What would you suggest - start tracing as `client` in my service Foo and then just consider all following services as servers?

Setup: k8s microservices, jaeger metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `span.kind=server` tag denotes an entry span, e.g. a span created in the local code in response to an external request. Likewise, `span.kind=client` denotes an exit span, e.g. a call made from the local code to another server.

In your example, the span generated for Foo is a `span.kind=server` and the span recording the call to Buzz is a `span.kind=client`.

Also see https://opentracing.io/specification/ and https://github.com/opentracing/specification/blob/master/semantic_conventions.md

Comment: Where can I read more about it ? And what does SPAN_KIND_CONSUMER, SPAN_KIND_INTERNAL and SPAN_KIND_PRODUCER means ?